# How to use PHP - AJAX with mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have this *levelselector.php* page, where players can pick one of the levels. This works fine, but I want to add an extra thing. The table of the levels shows the level name, the difficulty, the count of completers (solved), and if the actual player has completed it.

[This is the table with the levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkzyc.png)

**Here's what I want to do with AJAX**: If I move the mouse over the CELL which shows how many players have completed the map, **I want a** little **DIV** that follows the mouse **to show who the completers are**. I already have the div which only appeares when the player moves over the "Solved" CELL, but I want to fill this "div" with the completers of the actual map. These completers are stored in a database, in which all the levels are stored with all their parameters, in another file, it doesn't matter.

[This is the div which I want to fill with the actual level's completers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X67XV.jpg)

I was thinking this way: with Javascript I get the name of the Level name by getting the first "TD"-s innerHTML, and if I could give this name to PHP it would fill the DIV with the completers of the level the mouse over on is.

Here is my *script.js* code:

```
function delegate(parent, selector, type, fn) {
    function delegatedFunction(event) {
        let handler = this;
        let target = event.target;

        const closest = target.closest(selector);
        if (handler.contains(closest)) {
            fn.call(closest, event);
        }
    }
    parent.addEventListener(type, delegatedFunction);
}

delegate($("table"), "td[id=completed]", "mouseover", showCompleters);
delegate($("table"), "td[id=completed]", "mouseout", hideCompleters);


async function showCompleters() {
    var cursorsdiv = document.getElementById("completers");
    cursorsdiv.style.visibility = "visible";

    var levelname = this.closest("tr").firstElementChild.innerHTML;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("name", levelname);

    const response = await fetch('levelselector.php', {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    });
    const data = await response;

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        cursorsdiv.style.left = x + 20 + 'px';
        cursorsdiv.style.top = y + 10 + "px";
    } )
}

function hideCompleters() {
    var cursorsdiv = document.getElementById("completers");
    cursorsdiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

(I used this delegate function to add each lines of the table mouseover events)

And here is the *levelselector.php*'s html table part:

```
<table id="levelsTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Difficulty</th>
            <th>Solved</th>
            <th>Completed by me</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($levels as $level): ?>
        <tr id="level">
            <td id="levelname"><?= $level['level'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $level['difficulty'] ?></td>
            <td id="completed"><?= count($level['completed_by']) ?></td>
            <td><?php if(in_array($_SESSION['username'],$level['completed_by'])) {
                echo "Yes";
            } else {
                echo "No";
            } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

    <div id="completers"><?= CONTENT WITH THE ACTUAL LEVEL'S COMPLETERS ?></div>

    <script src="./levels/script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This DIV with the "completers" id would be the div which displays the completers, according to which level you move the mouse over.

Aaand here is what I could figure out in the PHP part:

```
<?php

    $levels = load_file("levels.json");

    if($_POST) {
        $levelname = $_POST['name'];
    }else {
        $levelname = "";
    }
?>
```

But sadly I don't understand how this AJAX works.

**The question**: How do you properly use AJAX in this case to fill the DIV with different content each line of the table if the mouse is moved over?

Hope you understood my english, thanks for all your help, appreciate it!!!

Peter